# GIS: Shapefile converted to GeoJSON has unexpected coordinate format

Tags: gis, shapefile, geopandas

I have taken a shapefile from [this page](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kioja4ofr2azihn/AACSCu9nvAG_a-6wiM2y4TF8a?dl=0) and I converted it to a GeoJSON file using Python and Geopandas like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
file = gpd.read_file("file.shp")
file.to_file("file.json", driver="GeoJSON")
```

Here's an example line from the GeoJSON:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": "DE63F0FA-CD3A-41A6-9524-C9C017A8DA64", "FEATCODE": 15014, "SQM": 148.245050005 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 385615.56, 249868.31000000029, 0.0 ], [ 385605.58, 249865.36, 0.0 ], [ 385601.55, 249879.03, 0.0 ], [ 385611.53, 249881.97, 0.0 ], [ 385615.56, 249868.31000000029, 0.0 ] ] ] } }
```

The coordinates clearly aren't lat/longs. In addition there's an extraneous 0 in each set of coordinates.

What format is this? How can I convert it to a lat/long?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this coordinate system is OSGB36.

I am currently using proj4 to convert the data to WGS84.

Comment: @MichaelEntin interesting. I'm surprised geopandas didn't reproject itself during the conversion given that geojson is supposed to use wgs84.

Comment: I had the same issue before. They indeed should reproject and give users a warning I think.